# How to build 4 projects(example) and make them access each other?

Tags: java, eclipse, split, workspace

How do I make something like 4 project and make them see each other, like a .xhtml to a Bean and a Bean to the interface that implements the method to save or read something from the database?

Comment: What do you mean by split workspace?  Do you mean have two different workspace locations?   What does that have to do with reading from a database?

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit the .xhtml in one pane while you observe the Bean in another pane simultaneously?  Your question is unclear.  Are you coming from a different development environment that offers a feature called "split workspace"?  Which one?  I'm sure someone here has used it and knows whether Eclipse has an analogous feature.

Comment: I messed it up, is a project that is based in 4 projects(example), that one file can access files from another project

Answer (score 1):

The other solution would be to:

- use only one workspace (meaning each components see each other)
- define [task context](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide#Context) with **[Mylyn](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/index.php)** in order to switch from one component to another and see only what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot split workspace. You can create as many workspaces as you want and add there as many projects as you want. To create new workspace just create directory and then start eclipse and give it this directory as a workspace. It will do everything automatically.

Unfortunately your second question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project; choose Properties.  Click on Project References and select the other projects.